# How to compare two images with iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

suppose i have taken one picture from my iphone camera and now i want to compare this image with other images and find best match image from that.

is it possible or not?

Answer (score 4):

there is very less help available for the image processing algorithms in objectiveC, but you can go in deep with **Quartz 2D** and try to compare images
even [Image processing on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120447/image-processing-on-the-iphone) link may be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing built into the SDK for comparing images, but any C library for image comparison can probably be used.  This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843972/image-comparison-fast-algorithm) has a good discussion on image comparison algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just comparing the differences between the two images or are you trying to match objects in the images with objects in other images?

If it's the latter then you may need to look into computer vision and stereo image analysis, particularly image rectification and point matching.

Computer Vision - A Modern Approach by Jean Ponce and David Forsyth is a fairly good book.