# Compare two images and get the percent difference

Tags: opencv, imagemagick

I known some ways to compare 2 images with ImageMagick or OpenCV

- [Using Objective-C, is there any way to compare two images and get a % difference value returned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749862/using-objective-c-is-there-any-way-to-compare-two-images-and-get-a-difference)
- http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/#methods
- [How can I quantify difference between two images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189943/how-can-i-quantify-difference-between-two-images)
- [Image comparison - fast algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843972/image-comparison-fast-algorithm?lq=1).

But for my case, I also have the same character with different position.
**Image1:**

[image]

**Image2:**

[image]

or

[image]
or

[image]

So, what should I do now to find the % difference value between Image1 and Image2?

Comment: You probably need to detect the boundaries of the black in the image and then normalise so every image is the same size etc. If you can find a straight line you could maybe also rotate it so they are being compared on the same axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually answers your question - which doesn't in fact ask anything about images 3 and 4 - but I fear it will not help you much.

As @GPPK suggests, you need to trim the extraneous material off around your kanji characters, which you can do with the `-trim` command in ImageMagick. I have added a thin red border so you can see where the edges are:

```
convert kanji2.png -trim kanji2-t.png
```

[image]

If you want do that to images 1 and 2, and then compare them, you can do that all in one go like this:

```
convert -metric ae kanji1.png kanji2.png -trim -compare -format "%[distortion]" info:
0
```

which shows there are zero pixels different in the resulting images if you trim kanji1 and kanji2.

If you compare the trimmed kanji1 and kanji3 like this, you get:

```
convert -metric AE kanji1.png kanji3.png -trim -compare -format "%[distortion]" info:
893184
```

which indicates 900,000 pixels of 5,000,000 are different.

Likewise, if you compare kanji1 and kanji4:

```
convert -metric AE kanji1.png kanji4.png -trim -compare -format "%[distortion]" info:
1.14526e+06
```

or 1.1 million of 5 million.

But this doesn't help when your images are a different size (scale), or rotated.

You could scale your images to a normalised size before comparing, and I guess that might help you become a bit more *"scale invariant"*:

```
convert -metric AE kanji1.png kanji4.png -trim -scale 1000x1000! -compare -format "%[distortion]" info:
```

You could also rotate your images using a little iterative procedure that rotates the images through say +/- 20 degrees and chooses the one with the smallest trimmed bounding box to become a little more *"orientation invariant"*. But then you will still have a problem if the characters are sheared, or fatter, or thinner, or brighter, or darker, or contrastier... I think you need to look into *"Template Matching"*.

Comment: Thank you.
Can you provide some OpenCV code sample?